# Parameterizing propertynames using expressions

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am having a piece of code in which i delegate certain properties of a class to another class if the class exists. Below you see the start time being defined on the TimeProvider if it exists.

```
public override DateTime StartTime
{
   get
   {
       return (TimeProvider != null) ? TimeProvider.StartTime : base.StartTime;
   }
   set
   {
       if (TimeProvider != null)
       {
           TimeProvider.StartTime = value;
       }
       else
       {
           base.StartTime = value;
       }
    }
 }
```

Now my 'problem' is that i have a lot more properties (like endtime,currentime) i delegate to the TimeProvider if it is not null. So i would like to have code like:

```
public override DateTime StartTime
{
   get
   {
       return GetTime(()=>StartTime);
   }
   set
   {
       SetTime(()=>StartTime)
    }
 }
```

Where the ()=>StartTime expression is sometimes 'evaluated' on the TimeProvider and sometimes on the class itself (they share a baseclass). Can something like this be done? Preferably without using reflection.

Comment: What's your final goal? Could it be achieved easier by implementing an ITimeProvider interface? You could probably do something that used the property names and reflection.

Comment: Both classes already share the same ITimeProvider interface. Only i would like to write all the delegation checks only once.

Comment: If your class was an ITimeProvider why don't you just set this.StartTime? Can you provide some context about why you want to do this? I don't really understand.

Comment: The first code is the implementation of a subclass of a class implementing ITimeProvider. The subclass has the feature of delegating its settings to an 'injected' TimeProvider whereas the base class has default properties. I hope this makes a little more clear?

Comment: So, the base class never needs to set the inner TimeProvider, and the sub class should always check; they are 2 different usage scenarios. Adding a common solution (i.e. your helper method) will complicate that. If your sub class gets extended further, the new sub-sub-class doesn't need to use the common solution, it can just rely on sub-class' (it's parent's) implementation.

Comment: The inner timeprovider is only known in the subclass...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake

```
public class Foo
{
    private string _string1;
    public Foo foo { get; set; }

    private T GetProperty<T>(Func<Foo,T> getter)
    {
        return foo == null
                   ? getter(this)
                   : getter(foo);
    }

    private void SetProperty(Action<Foo> setter)
    {
        if (foo == null)
            setter(this);
        else
            setter(foo);
    }

    public string String1
    {
        get { return GetProperty(a => a._string1); }
        set { SetProperty(a => a._string1 = value); }
    }
}
```